# How to setState in store redux after createAsyncThunk fullfilled?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

How to setState when state in store redux have value fullfilled from createAsyncThunk?

This is mycode. I don't know how to setState with value when createAsyncThunk returns fullfilled. I hope everyone can help me.

**createSlice:**

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import dataApi from '../../../apis/dataApi'

export const getBoardDetail = createAsyncThunk(
  'board/getBoardDetail',
  async (boardId, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await dataApi.get(`/api/board/${boardId}`)
      return response.data
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data)
    }
  }
)

const boardDetailSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'getBoardDetail',
  initialState: {
    loading: false,
    boardDetail: {},
    error: null
  },
  reducer: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getBoardDetail.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true
    },
    [getBoardDetail.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false
      state.boardDetail = payload.board
    },
    [getBoardDetail.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false,
      state.error = payload.message
    }
  }
})

export default boardDetailSlice.reducer
```

**store:**

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import boardDetailReducer from './slice/board/boardDetailSlice'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    boardDetail: boardDetailReducer,
  }
})

export default store
```

**React Component:**

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { loading, boardDetail } = useSelector(state => state.boardDetail)
    const [board, setBoard] = useState({})
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getBoardDetail('62159e7c8a97ca4a13f11542'))
      console.log(boardDetail) //boardDetail = {}
      setBoard(boardDetail)
  }, [dispatch])
  
    return (
      ....
    )
  }
```

How to boardDetail have a value then setBoard(boardDetail) after dispatch(getBoardDetail('62159e7c8a97ca4a13f11542'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured the slice under `boardDetail`.

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    boardDetail: boardDetailReducer,
  }
})
```

Thus the slice's state is available under `boardDetail` in the root state.

The state parameter of the extra reducers is the slice state. Since you defined the slice state as

```
initialState: {
  loading: false,
  boardDetail: {},
  error: null
},
```

you add another "sub state" `boardDetail`. Thus when you select

```
 state => state.boardDetail
```

it will return the slice's state, which is the structure you defined as the initial state. Thus deconstructing the `rootState.boardDetail` destructs the slice state. Not the `boardDetail` within the slice state:

```
 const { loading, boardDetail } = useSelector(state => state.boardDetail)
```

The naming makes it's easy to get confused when you think about `boardDetail`. I added an working example (Run code snippet) where I renamed the variables to make clear what I mean.

So your state finally looks like this:

{
boardDetail : {
loading,
boardDetail : {
...
}
}
}

Your `console.log(boardDetail) //boardDetail = {}` runs immediately after you dispatched the action. But `boardDetail` has not been updated yet.

One more thing... You don't need to use `useState`. Redux already provides a state and you can use it.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@4.1.2/dist/redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@7.2.6/dist/react-redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reduxjs/toolkit@1.7.1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@1.6.1/dist/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { combineReducers, createStore } = Redux;
const { Provider, connect, useSelector, useDispatch } = ReactRedux;
const { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, configureStore } = RTK;

const getBoardDetail = createAsyncThunk(
  'board/getBoardDetail', async (boardId) => {
      return {
        board: {
            title: `Board ${boardId}`
        }
      }
  }
)

const boardDetailSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'getBoardDetail',
  initialState: {
    loading: false,
    boardDetail: {},
    error: null
  },
  reducer: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getBoardDetail.pending]: (sliceState) => {
      sliceState.loading = true
    },
    [getBoardDetail.fulfilled]: (sliceState, { payload }) => {
      sliceState.loading = false
      sliceState.boardDetail = payload.board
    },
    [getBoardDetail.rejected]: (sliceState, { payload }) => {
      sliceState.loading = false,
      sliceState.error = payload.message
    }
  }
})

const boardDetailReducer = boardDetailSlice.reducer;

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    boardDetailSlice: boardDetailReducer,
  }
})

const Dashboard = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    const { loading, boardDetail } = useSelector(rootState => rootState.boardDetailSlice)    
       
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getBoardDetail('62159e7c8a97ca4a13f11542'))
  }, [dispatch])
  
    return <h2>{boardDetail.title}</h2>
  }

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Dashboard/></Provider>, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```